# Restore WordPress Backup Locally?

Tags: query

I was hosting a WordPress website with a web hosting service in 2015 and ended up canceling hosting due to issues at the time. I still have a backup of the WordPress website saved on my computer. I do not wish to purchase new web hosting and a domain and make the site public, however, I do wish to view the website locally, on my computer. Is this possible to do? If so, how would the process be done?

I have found several tutorials, articles, and videos surrounding this topic, though I am unsure if these are correct. Many suggest using XAMPP.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Jon, what kind of backup do you have?   Often it is the sql statements that would be needed to recreate the content of the site.

You could view them in a text editor to see what's there.   if you search for 'posts' for example you would find the insert statements to recreate the pages & posts.   If you wish to see the website the way it was, you would also need the theme that was being used and any plugins that were being used, any media files and yes of course also a server (such as a XAMPP or WAMP setup) running wordpress.   Then you rebuild the website.